# Can't turn grayscale on Epson printer

Tags: 18.04, printing, asus, epson

Well, the title says it all. I can't turn on grayscale on my Epson XP-235. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an Asus Vivo X556UQ. What I've tried:

- To enable it through Settings>Printers but whenever I click to change the value, it toggles itself back to off.
- Enabling grayscale trough the advanced parameters when printing an specific file is possible, but ignored by my printer which prints in color anyway.

I'm not new to Ubuntu but I'm far from being a connaisseur. I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance :) !

PS: This is my very first post, so if you have some constructive criticism or if you saw something I did wrong please tell me.

Nehuen

Answer (score 0):

Initially posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525809/341192). It involves a solution for Canon, but it worked with HP in my case.

In *System - Printers*, selecting the printer's properties, going to "Job options" - "Other options", down at the end there is an empty field to add a new option; fill that field with ***CNGrayscale*** and click "Add".

The new option is now listed under "Other options", but has an empty field: fill that with ***TRUE***, then click "Apply".

[image]

Now the new option *CNGrayscale* has a true/false switch that you can use to change between color and monochrome printing.